# What is client code in java

Tags: java, android, client

I have simple question. Of course before i asked here , i asked Google, but unfortunately i didn't get the answer i want.

I just want to know simple question. **What is client code in java (android)?**
When i asked google, it gave me results about client/network server. I think in this case a client is a program running on my/your computer, and network is a server communicating with client?

I want to know what is a client code in Java? Like in this context: ( Copied from android developers site )

*There are two reasons that a service can be run by the system. If someone calls Context.startService() then the system will retrieve the service (creating it and calling its onCreate() method if needed) and then call its onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) method with the arguments **supplied by the client.***

Is in this case client code like Activity code ..or?

Comment: what do you mean by client code?

Comment: wanna to know what is view part in android?

Comment: I think he's looking for an explanation of the term "client".

Comment: Read my question good. I gave the example from android site..

Comment: Yes. I just want to know what is "client code" in this example.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In this context, *client* means *client of the API*, which is simply the caller of the given methods or user of the given classes.

Comment: Thanks +1. SO a client can be subclass which inherits API class. Am i clear?

Comment: Yes, that's possible.

Comment: It is right. FYI, [here](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/12oop/) read: **A client is a program that uses a data type**. And **an implementation is the code that implements the data type specified in an API**.

Answer (score 2):

If activity A call's `onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)` of activity B, then activity A is the client. In this context, it simply means the caller of a method and/or service.

When looking at webservices, the 'server' retrieving the requests is called the server. The 'client' calling the webservice, is the client. When the 'server' calls another server, this server calling the other server can also be seen as a client.

A client can also be seen as a customer. [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer).

Answer (score 0):

Client code ?

What kind of client code you want?

A web based client code?

An application client code?

or Simply a client code?

Client - A thing which requests for something for something.

Something( any service, any information, any content or any answers or for answers)

Comment: From android developers site:

There are two reasons that a service can be run by the system. If someone calls Context.startService() then the system will retrieve the service (creating it and calling its onCreate() method if needed) and then call its onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) method with the arguments supplied by the client.

"supplied by the client" .I just want to know what is client in this example.

Comment: @rootpanthera Client is nothing but it is you or your android device. Which you use to send requests with parameters.